# Python; TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, input, typeerror

So basically I don't understand why my code is giving me this error, I tried looking it up, but I do not understand the error or how it affects me. This is my code for a simple shop simulator.

```
isBuying = True

#Create a map for our store's inventory. Each item in our store will have a string name and a floating point number for its price.
store = [('arrows', 20.00), ('bombs', 40.00), ('heart container', 120.00),
         ('sword', 100.00), ('potion', 15.00)]


#Define a function to print out the store's inventory. This function will take in an inventory.
def PrintStore(inventory):
  #For every item in the inventory, it will print out the item name and price in our formatted way.
  for item in inventory:
    print(' ' * 4 + item[0] + '.' * 3 + ' ' * 4 + str(item[1]))


while isBuying:
  #Use our function to print out our store's inventory.
  PrintStore(store)
  #Ask the user what they would like to buy and store the input in a variable. Lowercase it to prevent case sensitivity.
  input = input('What would you like to buy?\n')
  input = input.lower()

  #For every item in our store, check to see if our input is equal to the item's name. If it is, print out the item's price.
  for item in store:
    if input == item[0]:
      print(f'That will be {item[1]} dollars.')

  answer = input('Would you like to continue shopping?\n')
  answer = answer.lower()

  if answer == 'n' or 'no':
    isBuying = False
```

The error is on line `answer = input('Would you like to continue shopping?\n')` and the error is `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Don't use builtin names like "input" as variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefine the `input` builtin function

```
input = input('What would you like to buy?\n')
```

and now it's just a string. After that you call the `input`

```
answer = input('Would you like to continue shopping?\n')
```

but it is just a string (`str`) not a function. This is why you shouldn't use builtin functions as variable names.